# How to find last execution time of a stored procedure during last one year?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, exec

I have a stored procedure which is not run on a very frequent basis. So I want to find the last execution date of that stored procedure.

I used this query:

```
select distinct 
    s.last_execution_time
from 
    sys.dm_exec_query_stats s
cross apply 
    sys.dm_exec_query_plan (s.plan_handle) p
where 
    object_name(p.objectid, db_id('My_Db_Name')) = 'MY_Sp_Name' `
```

It returns no output. So is there any alternate way to check weather the stored procedure ran during last month or not?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The DMVs only track information since the last time the SQL Server service was restarted (or failed over, etc). So, no, if you don't already have logging enabled within this procedure, or aren't tracking it yourself in other ways (e.g. trace or monitoring tools), no, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 2):

Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280701.aspx

sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats may keep the last run around longer, but I am not sure when it clears.  Try this and see if it shows your last execution:

```
SELECT  
   p.object_id
   ,d.database_id
   ,p.name
   ,d.cached_time
   ,d.last_execution_time
   ,d.total_elapsed_time
   ,d.total_elapsed_time/d.execution_count AS [avg_elapsed_time]
   ,d.last_elapsed_time
   ,isnull(d.execution_count, 0) as ExecCount
   ,p.create_date as CreateDate
   ,p.modify_date as ModifyDate
FROM 
   sys.procedures p 
left join 
   sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats AS d 
   on d.object_id = p.object_id
WHERE 
   is_ms_shipped = 0
ORDER BY 
   create_date asc;
```